# Rendering custom nested html in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, vue.js

I'm moving a site from AngularJS 1.x that relies heavily on the $compile service (which is no longer available in Angular 2.x.  In the application I have a directive that looks something like this `<myDir elemId="someRestEndPointID"></myDir>`
and does the following:

1) A http call is made and the response returns a string that contains a directive `<myDir elemId="someRestEndPointID"></myDir>`

2) A call is made to the server to for /someRestEndPointID

3) Angular gets the content and renders and looks for another `<myDir>` tag

4) the process is repeated (recursive)

I have not yet found something that does this for our new framework Vue.js.  Is there a similar feature or library that would achieve this logic in Vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a convoluted way to work and I wouldn't follow that pattern. Why not create a component that takes an endpoint as a property `<your-component endpoint="https://example.org/"></your-component>` and then component will do the call inside the `create` method?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="loading.jpg" v-show="loading" />
    <!-- Content here -->
    {{content}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
   props: ['endpoint'],
   data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      content: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get(this.endpoint).then(resp => {
      this.content = resp.body;
      this.loading = false;
    });
   }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Would love to, but that pattern is already established by the Angular app. ie the response from the server serves data structured this way.

Comment: Hmm... Would you be able to pull the endpoint out of the div they send back and create a component with it using https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile ?

Comment: Closer and closer I think, but the render function is sync and the data is async.  I think we have to call the render function is a non-sync fashion.  Can you do that?

Comment: I made this. https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/128/ if you're able to grab the endpoint you could just have a parent component that creates the children and appends it to itself.

Comment: I updated it with an interval so it shows appending every second. https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/129/  hopefully that helps come up with a solution

Comment: That's great, but the template of some post would basically be the content from the server (and that content can have an embedded tag).

Comment: You can create the template when newing up the SomePost https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/131/

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution but only with the caveat that you'd have to write your own content parser to make this work in Vue.js.